# View resolving does not always work

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a Spring Boot (V 1.3.5) Web Application with JSPs packaged as jar. The views are located in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/views`.

See http://hillert.blogspot.lu/2016/03/spring-boot-with-jsp-in-executable-jar.html on that subject.

This works well on my Fedora dev. workstation, and as well on a colleague's with Windows 7, both using Eclipse Mars.

But on another Windows 8 PC, the same sourcecode run in Eclipse or STS, produces a 404 because no view can be found, and this starts aching my head seriously.

I append my configuration class here, maybe someone has an idea what could go wrong here.

```
package our.base.package;

import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
//@EnableWebMvc 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "our.base.package" })
public class SpringConfigRootApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        final CookieLocaleResolver slr = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        slr.setCookieMaxAge(86400 * 365 * 5);
        slr.setCookieName("lang");
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        final LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        lci.setIgnoreInvalidLocale(true);
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setRequestContextAttribute("requestContext");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }



    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public Application application() {
        return new Application();
    }

}
```

Comment: Packaging JSPs in `META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/views` is, in my opinion, a horrible hack and I'm not entirely surprised to hear that it doesn't work on Windows. Why not package your application as an executable war file instead?

Comment: As detailed in the question, it works on Windows when deployed as a jar. It also works when running the project in Eclipse, just not on one single Win 8.1 dev. station. I might go back to a war with embedded Tomcat, I just found it more natural to package as jar. I did not know that the "META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/views"-thing is a hack.